# PHP Contact Form that shows success and error Message on the same page

Tags: php, forms, echo, contact-form

I have created a PHP contact form on my site which works well except to see the Success or Error message it sends users to a the thank-you.php page. That is how I have it set up but I want users to submit and the form should dissapear and say Thank You! in place of the form.

Here is my HTML for the form:

```
<form class="form-foot" action="thank-you.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Footer contact form</legend>
<div class="field">
<label for="name">Your name: </label>
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="required field-name" required>
</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="email">Your email: </label>
<input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" class="required  field-email" required>
</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="message">Message: </label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="8" class="required field-message" placeholder="Your message" required></textarea>
</div>
<div class="field-submit">
<input class="sendbutton" type="submit"/>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And here is my PHP in the thank-you.php page:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "myemail@mysite.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

How can I make the form disappear on submission and echo the Thank You success message without going to thank-you.php or refreshing the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<form class="form-foot" action="thank-you.php" method="post">
```

with:

```
<form name="myform" class="form-foot" action="" method="post">
```

Give a name to your submit button:

```
<input name="submit" class="sendbutton" type="submit"/>
```

Move the code from thank-you.php to yourform.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "myemail@mysite.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You!";
}
```

Comment: Hi Jocelyn, ok that works great, but is there anyway of making the Thank You message appear without refreshing the page?

Comment: You will probably need to use AJAX if you do not want the page to reload.

Comment: Can you help with that all Jocelyn please, I don't know my way around AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax to post data to the thank-you.php file, from javascript. by calling a function on submit instead of the action attribute in the form. the function can have the below format

```
var url = "thank-you.php";
var data = $('#your-form-id').serialize();


$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {

        }    
   });
```

On getting the message from the thank-you page you can make use of it to assign it the html containing the form to replace the form with thank you!